# Qt5 with MSVC 2008 compiler

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I am trying to setup Qt5 to use MSVC 2008 compiler. So what I have done so far is:

1. Install MS Visual Studio 2008
2. Install Qt5 (with Qt creator), I used auto detect qt installer from the qt downloads page.
3. Attempting to setup Qt creator kit for MSVC 2008 compiler:

   - Qt has auto detected my compiler: MS c++ Compiler 9.0(x86)
   - Tried to make a Qt version, but the qmake paths are only for `C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2012\bin` and `C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2010\bin`.

So it looks like I need a specific qmake setup for MSVC 2008 c++ compiler. I don't know how I can get this, can I just use the MSVC compiler?... any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there are pre-built binaries for VS2008 for Qt5.5. Have you tried building from the source code?

Comment: @RobbieE No I have not, I have been looking around and I think I am coming to the same conclusion! - I guess I need to build it with the vs2008 compiler using nmake?